# handle my website URLs in my app

Tags: android, url, android-manifest

i want to handle my website urls in my android app
for example :
when user in any app click on http://www.example.com/username

my app open and show username information

i use this code for open my app when click on http://www.example.com , but google chrome started :(

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:host="www.example.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Comment: use webview https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: What is it in your app where the user can click on this URL? A Button, a text view, a document shown in a WebVeiw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `android.intent.action.VIEW` and `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` to the activity's intent filter.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="www.example.com" android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

For more information 
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html#adding-filters